# sql add sequential second to time

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that holds test data for returned products.  The Test_Time is a string that shows date, hour and minute.  I would like to update the database to include seconds so I can display results in chronological order.  I ran a query to put the records in order (ORDER BY SN, RMA_NUM, Test_Time, ID)

Results:

```
ID      SN       RMA_NUM     Test_Time       FAULT_TYPE
3119    CACA014  FH76085254  10/29/2015 08:27   A1
3120    CACA014  FH76085254  10/29/2015 08:27   B8
8923    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:11   A2
8924    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:14   B3
8925    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:14   B6
1651    CADA091  FH67974034  09/18/2015 09:30   A4
1652    CADA091  FH67974034  09/18/2015 09:30   A4
5267    CADA091  FH76347276  11/17/2015 12:31   A9
5268    CADA091  FH76347276  11/17/2015 12:31   C1
```

How to I write SQL to update the Test_Time to include a unique second?

So my results will look like this:

```
ID      SN       RMA_NUM     Test_Time             FAULT_TYPE
3119    CACA014  FH76085254  10/29/2015 08:27:01      A1
3120    CACA014  FH76085254  10/29/2015 08:27:02      B8
8923    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:11:01      A2
8924    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:14:02      B3
8925    CACA042  FH83872608  02/08/2016 09:14:03      B6
1651    CADA091  FH67974034  09/18/2015 09:30:01      A4
1652    CADA091  FH67974034  09/18/2015 09:30:02      A4
5267    CADA091  FH76347276  11/17/2015 12:31:01      A9
5268    CADA091  FH76347276  11/17/2015 12:31:02      C1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (test_time + ':' +
        right('00' + cast(row_number() over (partition by sn order by id) as varchar(255)), 2)
       ) as new_test_time
from t;
```

I would suggest, though, that you store date/times as `datetime`.

EDIT:

You can use this for an update:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (test_time + ':' +
              right('00' + cast(row_number() over (partition by sn order by id) as varchar(255)), 2)
             ) as new_test_time
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set test_time = new_test_time;
```

Comment: Awesome, the query works... thank you, Gordon.   How do I incorporate UPDATE statement to update the Test_Time field?

Comment: Perfect... Thanks again!